# How to Maximize Linux Vps Desktop environment resolution

Tags: server, xfce, display-resolution, desktop-environments, vnc

I've bought **Linux Vps** and I installed an **ubuntu server 16.04 lts** on my system, which is ubuntu 20.04 lts. Then I installed the Xfce Desktop environment by installing **Vnc** and **TigerVnc Viewer**.

The Question is VPS's Desktop Resolution. Check the Image:
[image]

Now I login into `Xfce Desktop`:

[image]

I'm Maximizing Desktop:

[image]

See? How can I use full screen or 1920x1080 or other Resolutions in my Linux Vps Desktop?

 I've tried to change the Screen options in VNC Viewer, didn't make any difference.

[image]

I've also tried this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
..
..
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="consoleblank=0"  
.. 
..
```

Added this `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x24` into it: (Updated)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="1024x768x24"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="consoleblank=0"  
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x24
```

then updated the `grub`

No Difference(In Both of the Desktop and CMD line Resolution).

Comment: Please clarify your release.  You mention 16.04 then 20.04, so which is installed? XFCE/Xubuntu is also EOL on 16.04 and thus if your machine is online, you're using a partially unpatched/unsupported system (*flavors* come with 3 years of support;t eh oldest XFCE/Xubuntu with security fixes is currently 18.04)  Please clarify your contridictions.

Comment: @guiverc i have 20.04 installed on m lptp + then i bought vps which its os is 16.04 ... i installed XFCE on my vps (16.04)